# Q: Hovering In Html

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with my menu bar not working with hover.  I tried it with another part of the page and it works just fine, but not with the menu.  What am I doing wrong here?

```css
.menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    background: #e7e3d4;
}

.menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    color: #b23850;
    margin: 0 13px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.menu ul li:hover{
    background: 8590AA;
    delay:.5s;
}
```

```html
        <div class="menu">
             <ul>
                 <li>Home</li>
                 <li>Services</li>
                 <li>Know Joe</li>
                 <li>Contact Us</li>
             </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: `#8590AA` not `8590AA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use background color property use # sign like below:

```
.menu ul li:hover {
    background: #8590AA;
}
```

```css
.menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    background: #e7e3d4;
}

.menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    color: #b23850;
    margin: 0 13px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu ul li:hover{
    background: #8590AA;
    transition: all 0.55 ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
             <ul>
                 <li>Home</li>
                 <li>Services</li>
                 <li>Know Joe</li>
                 <li>Contact Us</li>
             </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transition: background-color 0.5s` instead of `delay: 0.5s`

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  background: #e7e3d4;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #b23850;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #e7e3d4;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #8590AA;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Know Joe</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing # symbol in background property of **menu ul li:hover**
try with following

```
.menu ul li: hover{
 background: #8590AA;
 delay :0.5s;
 }
```